# Gatsby gives failed to validate error on Gatsby develop

Tags: wordpress, gatsby

Today I imported a gatsby website from a private repo which was configured for Netlify, and started to build the application locally using `gatsby develop`.

When I am in the process for gatsby develop, it gives this error:

```
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Post - 81.705s - fetched 432
Failed to validate error { ValidationError: "errno" is not allowed. "syscall" is not allowed.
"path" is not allowed. "dest" is not allowed
    at Object.exports.process (<Path to directory here>\node_modules\@hapi\joi\lib\errors.js:202:19)
    at internals.Object._validateWithOptions (<Path to directory here>\node_modules\@hapi\joi\lib\types\any\index.js:763:31)
    at internals.Object.validate (<Path to directory here>\node_modules\@hapi\joi\lib\types\any\index.js:797:21)
    at constructError (<Path to directory here>\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\structured-errors\construct-error.js:52:32)
    at Reporter.error (<Path to directory here>\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\reporter\reporter.js:135:59)
    at Reporter.panic (<Path to directory here>\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\reporter\reporter.js:75:34)
    at Object.panic (<Path to directory here>\node_modules\gatsby\src\utils\api-runner-node.js:210:16)
    at createRemoteMediaItemNode (<Path to directory here>\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental\src\steps\source-nodes\create-nodes\create-remote-media-item-node.js:354:24)        
  isJoi: true,
  name: 'ValidationError',
  details:
   [ { message: '"errno" is not allowed',
       path: [Array],
       type: 'object.allowUnknown',
       context: [Object] },
     { message: '"syscall" is not allowed',
       path: [Array],
       type: 'object.allowUnknown',
       context: [Object] },
     { message: '"path" is not allowed',
       path: [Array],
       type: 'object.allowUnknown',
       context: [Object] },
     { message: '"dest" is not allowed',
       path: [Array],
       type: 'object.allowUnknown',
       context: [Object] } ],
  _object:
   { context: {},
     errno: -4082,
     code: 'EBUSY',
     syscall: 'copyfile',
     path:
      '<Path to directory here>\\.cache\\caches\\gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental\\f4aa224be0bbd5be99b9a159c4cd9a3b\\SXP.png',
     dest:
      '<Path to directory here>\\.wordpress-cache\\wp-content\\uploads\\2020\\10\\SXP.png', 
     pluginName: 'gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental',
     text: 'There was an error',
     level: 'ERROR',
     stack: [],
     docsUrl: 'https://gatsby.dev/issue-how-to' },
  annotate: [Function] }
not finished source and transform nodes - 164.044s
not finished  gatsby-source-wordpress  fetching nodes - 160.782s - 2250 total
not finished  gatsby-source-wordpress  creating nodes - 4.250s
not finished  gatsby-source-wordpress  MediaItem - 4.257s - fetched 37
```

Can someone clarify as to what I should be doing to mitigate this error? If there is anything needed, I will add in subsequent edits.

Comment: Have you installed everything without errors? (npm/yarn install)  What version of `gatsby-cli` are you running?

Comment: I haven't encountered any errors in the installation. The gatsby versions I used is as such:

Gatsby CLI version: 2.19.1
Gatsby version: 2.31.1